# Macbook Pro 2015 15" Bootcamp does not allow ISO file option - requires USB

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, bootcamp, windows

I want to use Bootcamp for Windows on my 2015 Macbook Pro. After downloading the Windows ISO, however, Bootcamp is requiring a USB install instead of allowing me to choose the ISO file from on my computer. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You *must* have that USB otherwise you can't install Windows when it reboots.  BC uses the ISO along with downloaded drivers to create a custom USB installer.  See:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? Which version of Windows did yo download? How large is your drive? According to Apple's website [Install Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp Assistant](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468#more), you should not need a flash drive if your MacBook Pro is a 2015 model using El Capitan or later. Also, I assume you are using the latest Windows 10.

Comment: @Allan: In the past when we have differed on an answer, it always turned out you were right. However, here we both are giving the same link to an Apple website which explicitly states a 2015 MacBook Pro does **not** need a flash drive to install Windows. What am I missing here?

Comment: @DavidAnderson - My bad...I literally just answered a question about a 2013 MBP and got the model years mixed up.